# What is the proper way to quit an application in pyqt4?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4

I am studying pyqt4 and is following an tutorial on the internet. Somehow the quit line in the example code doesn't work:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
ZetCode PyQt4 tutorial 

This program creates a quit
button. When we press the button,
the application terminates. 

author: Jan Bodnar
website: zetcode.com 
last edited: October 2011
"""

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):               

        qbtn = QtGui.QPushButton('Quit', self)
        qbtn.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
        qbtn.resize(qbtn.sizeHint())
        qbtn.move(50, 50)       

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Quit button')    
        self.show()

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I pressed the X button or the Quit button in the gui, the console prompted some error:

```
Python 3.2.3 (default, Apr 11 2012, 07:15:24) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Raymond\Programming Practice\python\gui_qt\lesson1_basic\gui_quit.py", line 46, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\Raymond\Programming Practice\python\gui_qt\lesson1_basic\gui_quit.py", line 42, in main
    sys.exit(app.exec())
SystemExit: 0
```

I fixed the code by replacing the line

```
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

with the this line:

```
return app.exec()
```

Then the application exit gracefully. However I am not sure if this method has any disadvantage because it just return the status.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll find the correct syntax is `sys.exit(app.exec_())`

Note the underscore

It doesn't resolve the control+C issue but the program will exit without an error appearing on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that's not technically an error, it's an exception. While errors are exceptions, not all exceptions are necessarily errors. There are several "special" exceptions, such as `SystemExit`, `StopIteration`, etc..., which python uses for various different things. `sys.exit` raises the `SystemExit` exception in order to exit your program.

From the [Docs](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/sys.html):

> sys.exit([arg])
>
> Exit from Python. This is implemented by raising the SystemExit exception, so cleanup actions specified by finally clauses of try statements are honored, and it is possible to intercept the exit attempt at an outer level.
>
> The optional argument arg can be an integer giving the exit status (defaulting to zero), or another type of object. If it is an integer, zero is considered “successful termination” and any nonzero value is considered “abnormal termination” by shells and the like. Most systems require it to be in the range 0-127, and produce undefined results otherwise. Some systems have a convention for assigning specific meanings to specific exit codes, but these are generally underdeveloped; Unix programs generally use 2 for command line syntax errors and 1 for all other kind of errors. If another type of object is passed, None is equivalent to passing zero, and any other object is printed to stderr and results in an exit code of 1. In particular, sys.exit("some error message") is a quick way to exit a program when an error occurs.
>
> Since exit() ultimately “only” raises an exception, it will only exit the process when called from the main thread, and the exception is not intercepted.

So really, `sys.exit(app.exec())` is no different than `raise SystemExit(app.exec())`. The only thing you are really changing by adding `sys.exit` in this case is to return the exit code given by `app.exec()`.